# Is it possible to decouple these DEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have two differential equations
$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = a \frac{dr}{dt} - b\frac{dR}{dt},$$
and
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = c \frac{dr}{dt} + d\frac{dR}{dt}. $$

My goal here is not to *solve* the differential equations, only to rearrange it such that I can get something like that

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = f\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right), $$
where $f$ is independent $r'$ and $R'$.

The reason for this is because the system corresponds to a physical situation in which I can measure $x'$ and $y'$ but not $R'$ or $r'$., so I would really appreciate the help.

Two attempts I thought of:

- Solving one for $r'$ and plugging into the other. This method of elimination seems to not be possible unless I am missing something.
- It did occur to me that I could write the equation in terms of matrices (matrix). I thought that the eigenvalues and/or eigenvectors could be useful but here I wasn't sure how.
  $$ \pmatrix{y' \\ x'} = \pmatrix{a & -b \\ c & d}\pmatrix{r' \\ R'}.$$

I have had courses in differential equations, but we never covered anything like this.

Comment: The system is not derminted completely. Suppose that $R=0$ or $R=f(r)$, you can always get a solution.

Comment: I know that neither of those cases are true. Shouldn't I still be able to get a solution family?

Comment: Nope, not unless $$ad+bc=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{cases} \frac{dx}{dt} = a \frac{dr}{dt} - b\frac{dR}{dt}\\ \frac{dy}{dt} = c \frac{dr}{dt} + d\frac{dR}{dt} \end{cases} $$
This is a system of 2 equations with 4 unknown functions : $x(t)$ , $y(t)$ , $r(t)$ and $R(t)$.
This means that one can arbitrary chose two functions among the four and determine the two others. For example, chose arbitrary any functions $r(t)$ and $R(t)$, then the solution is :
$$\begin{cases} x(t) = \int \left(a \frac{dr}{dt}\right)dt - \int \left(b \frac{dR}{dt}\right)dt \\ y(t) = \int \left(c \frac{dr}{dt}\right)dt  + \int \left(d \frac{dR}{dt}\right)dt  \end{cases} $$
If the coefficients $a,b,c,d$ are not functions of $t$ :
$$\begin{cases} x(t) = a\:r(t)-b\:R(t)\\ y(t) = b\:r(t)+d\:R(t)  \end{cases} $$
with any functions $r(t)$ and $R(t)$.

IN ADDITION, after the wording of the question was updated :

As explained above, because they are only two equations for four unknown functions, each one among the unknown functions is related to two of the other ones. This means that $y'$ is related to $x'$ AND either with $r'(t)$ or with $R'(t)$ :
$$\begin{cases}
y'=-\frac{d}{b}x'+\frac{ad+bc}{b}r'\\
y'=\frac{c}{a}x'+\frac{ad+bc}{a}R'
\end{cases}$$
Thus, in the general case, a relationship of the kind $y'=f(x')$ is impossible.

Nevertheless, it is possible in particular case, if a particular relationship exists between $a,b,c,d$ :

If $\quad ad+bc=0\quad\implies\quad y'=k\:x' \quad\text{ with }\quad k=\frac{c}{a}=-\frac{d}{b}$

So, in this particular case, the function $f$ is a simple linear relationship, as expected since all relationships are linear in the whole problem.

Note that this particular case occurs when the determinant of the matrix $ \left|\begin{matrix}
  a & -b  \\
  c & d  
 \end{matrix}\right|=0$.

Comment: Thanks very much. I have edited my question. Is it possible instead to solve to get something of the form $y' = f(x')$, where $f$ is independent of $R'$ and $r'$?

Comment: See the addition to my first answer.